# Laravel 5.6 APP_DEBUG not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.6 app on Ubuntu running on bitnami nginxstack. I have set APP_DEBUG=true in .env file and LOG_CHANNEL=single. However,when I try to open any route that is not defined in web.php, I do not see the "Route not found" error instead I see only "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.". In previous versions, I use to see the detailed messages in a black screen, but it's not showing in Laravel 5.6. Can someone please help. I have already set correct permissions to log folder and Log::info('test') writes this message to laravel.log correctly.

Comment: You could install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to see detailed errors/warnings

Comment: Agree but wondering why isn’t it working by default. It used to work with earlier version though.